# find every time a line is referenced and then prink it each time in a separate sheet

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find each time a key work is sheet 2 is references in sheet 1 and for each one of those times print it in sheet 2. For Example is in sheet 2 A:1 it says dog and then in sheet 1 A:1, A:2, A:5 it also says dog then I would like in sheet 2 for 2:2 to be Sheet 1 1:1, for Sheet 2 3:3 to be Sheet 1 2:2 and for sheet 2 4:4 to be sheet 1 5:5.

Comment: Question is a little unclear, but what is the actual problem you're having?  What *specifically* about this are you not able to do?

Comment: Find all of the lines in one sheet and then list all of those lines based off of that criteria in another. In their entirety.